# Angular Cli core_1.Version is not a function

Tags: angular, angular-cli

When i was updating angular cli project to a newer version i get this error on command line after typing `ng init`. I have done everything as is typed on upgrading guide on Github site of AngularCli project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm encountering the same behavior. You might try logging this issue on the [angular-cli repo](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues).

Here's an excerpt from [another issue](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/343) suggesting a workaround:

> For now the best tip I can give for upgraders is that, if you want to upgrade a project to the newest CLI, then generate a new project, copy over all the base auto-generated files and npm install. That'll mostly guarantee that you have the most up to date ng new files as possible. Other stuff might still break though... but only if we fundamentally change generators.